# Nullable string type hinting gives syntax error in PHP 7.2

Tags: php, types, php-7.2

I'm using PHP 7.2 and trying to type hint this variable:

```php
class TestClass
{
    public static ?string $test = null;
```

But PHP gives me the following error:

> syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const
>   (T_CONST)

And I'm absolutely clueless why! Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Typed properties](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php#migration74.new-features.core.typed-properties) were not included until PHP 7.4.

Comment: Oh wow, I assumed these fell in the same category as 'type hinting' which is a 7 or 7.1 thing, I'm not exactly sure. Thanks! I'll accept your answer as soon as I can (10 more minutes)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, new knowledge.